# EasyMock am I doing this right?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, easymock

I'm building a JEE EAR application and I started working with EasyMock to create mocks for the repositories my services are using. But I am not quite sure the result is correct. Two tests in particular where I am testing void methods.

```
public class VenueServiceTest extends ServiceTest {

private VenueService venueService = new VenueServiceImpl();
private VenueRepository mockVenueRepository;    // interface that the service is using
private List<Venue> venues;
private Venue venue1;
private Venue venue2;

@Override
public void setupMock() {
    venues = MockUtils.getMockedVenues();
    venue1 = venues.get(0);
    venue2 = venues.get(1);
    mockVenueRepository = createMock(VenueRepository.class);
    venueService.setRepository(mockVenueRepository);
}

@Override
public void testUpdate() {
    Venue originalVenue = new Venue(0L, "The Venue");
    String originalName = originalVenue.getName();

    mockVenueRepository.update(originalVenue);
    expect(mockVenueRepository.findById(originalVenue.getId())).andReturn(originalVenue);
    replay(mockVenueRepository);

    originalVenue.setName("Another Venue");
    venueService.updateEntity(originalVenue);

    Venue newVenue = venueService.getEntity(originalVenue.getId());
    String newName = newVenue.getName();

    assertFalse("Venue names should not be equal", originalName.equals(newName));

    verify(mockVenueRepository);
}

@Override
public void testDelete() {
    expect(mockVenueRepository.findById(venue1.getId())).andReturn(venue1);
    mockVenueRepository.remove(venue1);
    expect(mockVenueRepository.findById(venue1.getId())).andReturn(null);

    replay(mockVenueRepository);


    assertNotNull(venueService.getEntity(venue1.getId()));
    venueService.deleteEntity(venue1);
    assertNull(venueService.getEntity(venue1.getId()));
    verify(mockVenueRepository);
}
```

Both of these test passes. But if I comment out the delet/update parts they still pass.

```
@Override
public void testUpdate() {
    Venue originalVenue = new Venue(0L, "The Venue");
    String originalName = originalVenue.getName();

    // mockVenueRepository.update(originalVenue);
    expect(mockVenueRepository.findById(originalVenue.getId())).andReturn(originalVenue);
    replay(mockVenueRepository);

    originalVenue.setName("Another Venue");
    // venueService.updateEntity(originalVenue);

    Venue newVenue = venueService.getEntity(originalVenue.getId());
    String newName = newVenue.getName();

    assertFalse("Venue names should not be equal", originalName.equals(newName));

    verify(mockVenueRepository);
}

@Override
public void testDelete() {
    expect(mockVenueRepository.findById(venue1.getId())).andReturn(venue1);
    //  mockVenueRepository.remove(venue1);
    expect(mockVenueRepository.findById(venue1.getId())).andReturn(null);

    replay(mockVenueRepository);


    assertNotNull(venueService.getEntity(venue1.getId()));
    //  venueService.deleteEntity(venue1);
    assertNull(venueService.getEntity(venue1.getId()));
    verify(mockVenueRepository);
}
```

Am I doing this right? My guess is no and if so how do you test this properly?

Thank you!

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing; but just as a starter: try using **createStrictMock**. Strict mocks, are well, much more strict. That makes it sometimes harder to use them (as they insist on the order of calls you specify on them), but on the other hand, them being strict is sometimes exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately that did not solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the update, you are recording to return `originalVenue`. Since you are modifying its name, it will indeed be different.  There is only one instance of `originalVenue` through all the test.

For delete, you are recording `venue1` and then `null`. So if you call `findById` twice, you will receive `venue1` and `null`. The test the delete, you can mock only the `remove` method to make sure it is called. Calling `getEntity` makes you test `getEntity` which is unrelated with the delete.

Basically, to test update and delete, I would do

```
@Override
public void testUpdate() {
    Venue originalVenue = new Venue(0L, "The Venue");
    String originalName = originalVenue.getName();

    mockVenueRepository.update(originalVenue);
    replay(mockVenueRepository);

    originalVenue.setName("Another Venue");
    venueService.updateEntity(originalVenue);

    verify(mockVenueRepository);
}

@Override
public void testDelete() {
    mockVenueRepository.remove(venue1);
    replay(mockVenueRepository);

    venueService.deleteEntity(venue1);

    verify(mockVenueRepository);
}
```

Comment: Thank! It makes more sense now :)